# Plot de linhas no ggplot

Tags: r

Tenho os seguintes dados:

```
Ano   PIB
2008  0.05
2009  0.00
2010  0.08
2011  0.04
2012  0.02
2013  0.03
2014  0.01
2015 -0.04
2016 -0.03
2017  0.01
2018  0.01
```

Quando faço o plot usando `geom_line` desses dados ele me retorna a curva, mas o eixo x, que seriam os anos, não aparecem ano a ano, sendo 2008, 2009, 2010 e assim por diante.

```
ggplot(dados1, aes(x = Ano, y = PIB)) +
  geom_line(size=1) + theme_minimal()
```

Ele retorna como mostra a imagem.

Como faço para ajustar esse eixo, para plotar a ordem correta dos anos?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Para anotar os eixos com os valores dos dados pode-se usar uma de

- `scale_?_discrete` dados inteiros ou `"factor"`;
- `scale_?_continuous` dados numéricos contínuos.

Mas é preciso ter atenção aos valores de `breaks` e `labels` que estas funções não herdam `aes()`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dados1, aes(x = Ano, y = PIB)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = dados1$Ano, labels = dados1$Ano) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Dados.**

```
dados1 <- read.table(text = "
Ano   PIB
2008  0.05
2009  0.00
2010  0.08
2011  0.04
2012  0.02
2013  0.03
2014  0.01
2015 -0.04
2016 -0.03
2017  0.01
2018  0.01
", header = TRUE)
```